# Notating more than three prime marks for related variables

Tags: math-mode

I'm using prime marks to distinguish several related variables, as I progress through a series of altered definitions:

```
$$\eqalign{
x'   &= \dots \cr
x''  &= \dots \cr
x''' &= \dots
}$$
```

What comes next? `$x_''''$` or `$x^{IV}$`? How can I notate the latter?

Thank you,

Comment: This doesn't really have anything to do with (La)TeX, and seems to solicit "primarily opinion-based answers".

Comment: @Werner I'm asking how to notate such a thing. I'm not after opinions, other than for alternate implementations.

Comment: I don't understand your comment. How to "notate `$x^{IV}$`"?

Comment: @KateF  What do you mean by the primes? Derivatives or something else?

Comment: @Werner Well, I'm asking if that's the correct way to mark up that superscript. Because of course the "I" in superscript "IV"  looks quite different from a prime mark, and I would want them to look visually related. Thank you!

Comment: @AboAmmar My variables aren't derivatives in the calculus sense; rather they are just related definitions which I introduce to the reader, as I'm gradually adjusting a model. So I give a definition for `$x$`, tweak it slightly, and call that `$x'$` and so on. (I wish MathJax were provided here...)

Comment: Sure, `x'` does not look the same as `x^I`. Why not just use something like `x_{\alpha}`, `x_{\beta}`, `x_{\gamma}`, `x_{\delta}`, ..., or perhaps the more preferred `x^{(i)}`, `x^{(ii)}`, `x^{(iii)}`, `x^{(iv)}`, ...?

Comment: If you have a long series, one notation I've seen is to use a number. It could be a subscript, or left superscript, or whatever won't be misinterpreted; or you could put it in parentheses so make it obvious that it's not an exponent: $x^{(4)}$. You may want to change your notation for the first three versions at that point too...

Comment: @Werner I have some other variables, and for consistency I'd like to use the same scheme for those, too. I may well switch everything to `x^{(i)}` style, but that's outside the scope of this question. Here I'm just asking about how `$x^{IV}$` might be written such that it seems proper next to a prime, so that I may judge if I think it's viable or not. I had considered `$x'^{V}$` but of course that's silly :)

Comment: To anybody who could enlighten me: Why was this question put on hold? Am I misunderstanding something about the purpose of this site?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd use  `\rm iv` or sometimes people use a prime:

```
$x''', x^{\rm iv}, \hbox{ or }  x^{\prime v} $

\bye
```

[image]

Comment: I'm using ConTeXt, but I gave my examples in plain TeX because I didn't see the need to exclude anybody else. Thanks for the example! I'm sure you can see how uncompelling those approaches look in context beside each other, due to the differences in style.

Comment: @KateF oh OK about ConteXt that's fine (I should probably delete that  first line in my answer-) as for style yes well x''' only really works as a scheme if you don't expect it to go on past 3, I'd use x^{(1)} or some such.